# Android onTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Need help, I am tring to make an android game as project for my school.
I try to use ontouchListener in order to bump the mole.

Main Activity

```
public class First_Stage extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

private AllViews allViews;
private MoleView moleView;
private PointsView pointsView;
private TimerView timerView;
private StageView stageView;
private Mole mole; 
private MoveMole moleMove;
private int points=0;
private StagePoints stagePoints;
private PointsSingelton poin;
private float x,y;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mole=new Mole();
    stageView=new StageView(this);
    moleView=new MoleView(this,mole,x,y);
    pointsView=new PointsView(this);
    timerView=new TimerView(this, "3:33");

    allViews=new AllViews(this);
    allViews.setViews(stageView, moleView, pointsView, timerView);

    setContentView(allViews);
    allViews.setOnTouchListener((View.OnTouchListener)this);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x=event.getX();
    y=event.getY();

    return true;
}
```

All views class

```
public class AllViews extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable{

private MoleView moleView;
private PointsView pointsView;
private TimerView timerView;
private StageView mainView;
private float x,y;
private Paint test;
private First_Stage first;
Thread drawThread = new Thread(this);
SurfaceHolder holder;


public AllViews(Context context) {
    super(context);
    test=new Paint();
    first=new First_Stage();
    holder= getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}


public void setViews(StageView mainView, MoleView moleView, PointsView pointsView,TimerView timerView)

{
    this.mainView = mainView;
    this.moleView = moleView;
    this.pointsView = pointsView;
    this.timerView = timerView;

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mainView.onDraw(canvas);    
    moleView.onDraw(canvas);
    pointsView.onDraw(canvas);
    timerView.onDraw(canvas);
    test.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(first.getX(), first.getY(), 40, test);

}



@Override
public void run() {
     Canvas c;
        while (true) {
            c = null;

            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized (holder) {
                    onDraw(c);

                }
            } finally {

                if (c != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

            }
        }                   
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    drawThread.start();     

}
```

I have also class to mole, points,time and the stage screen. but I don't know in which view to make the ontouchlistener. 
for a try I made a blue circle and try to change it's place with the new positions from the listener event but no lack.

any help will be great.
thanks,

cfir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to let `AllViews` know that you received the information from the touch.

You could create a couple of properties in `AllViews`

```
private int touchX;
private int touchY;

public void setTouchX(int x) { this.touchX = x; }

public void setTouchY(int y) { this.touchY = y; }
```

and then in your `onTouch` method add these lines before the `return` statement:

```
AllViews.setTouchX(x);
AllViews.setTouchY(y);
```

and finally, in your `onDraw` method, change

```
canvas.drawCircle(first.getX(), first.getY(), 40, test);
```

to

```
canvas.drawCircle(this.touchX, this.touchY, 40, test);
```

Answer (score 1):

The onTouchListener should be implemented in the AllViews class, since if you implement it in the other views, you'll get the position relative to left/top of the specific view.

in the onDraw of AllViews, you can draw the rest of your objects

Answer (score 1):

In which view you want to make an `onTouchListener`is up to you, but that `onTouchListener` is an interface which need to be implemented. And when implemented, you'll need the right method, which in this case I believe is `onTouch()`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)